# Mostrar BLOB em src de iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boa tarde, estou aqui a postar a minha dúvida porque já tentei alguns workarunds para conseguir o que eu quero e não estou a conseguir.

O meu objetivo é ocultar em primeira instancia o link principal que está na base de dados. Vamos supor que o link que está armazenado é www.google.com*

```
<img src="img/server.png" class="img-thumbnail servidor" data-videolink="www.google.com" data-server="servername"/>
```

Aqui eu chamo (com echo PHP) o data-videolink que é o link que está armazenado na base de dados.
Mas inves de mostrar www.google.com eu gostaria que mostrasse um blob (ou seja, que escondesse o endereco original como ja expliquei)

> Este é o meu js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#servidores-bg .servidor').click(function () {
        $('.container > #servidores-bg').hide();
        var videolink = $(this).data('videolink');  
//$('#servidores-player').prepend("<iframe src='"+videolink+"' id='player' scrolling='no' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen='true' webkitallowfullscreen='true' mozallowfullscreen='true'></iframe>"); <---- PREVIOUS CODE LINE
        $('#servidores-player').prepend("<iframe id='player'></iframe>");

        var html = ``; <-- A ideia que tive foi colocar o iframe com a src original da base de dados ao clicar na imagem com o data-video link mas percebi que não faz sentido isso :(
        var blob = new Blob([html], {type: 'text/html'});
        var iframe = document.querySelector("#player");
        iframe.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    });
});
```

Alguma ajuda? Estou mesmo preso aqui

Comment: Mas do que adianta você fazer tudo isso se no final vai por a url no src do iframe? Abrindo o inspetor de elementos vai dar pra ver a url do mesmo jeito.

Comment: Porque necessito mesmo

Answer (score 0):

Você já tem o `Blob`, então é só transformá-lo em texto novamente:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.servidor').click(function () {
    $('#servidores-bg').hide();
    var videolink = $(this).data('videolink');  
    $('#servidores-player').prepend("<iframe id='player'></iframe>");
    var blob = new Blob([videolink], {type: 'text/html'});
    var iframe = document.querySelector("#player");
    //transforma o blob em texto
    blob.text().then(url => iframe.src = url);
  });
});
```

Comment: Não é isso que procuro. Supostamente o BLOB devia estar no `data-videolink`. Assim: `data-videolink="blob:43334-34334-5657-5757"` e quando clico `<img data-videolink="blob:43334-34334-5657-5757">` chama o link original da base de dados como: `$('#servidores-player').prepend("<iframe src='"+videolink+"' id='player' scrolling='no' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen='true' webkitallowfullscreen='true' mozallowfullscreen='true'></iframe>");`